# Matlab: Loop through rows of matrix to calculate lowest value

Tags: matlab

I am working on a program that will take my 24x24 matrix (`P6`) and multiply each row by a 24x1 matrix `R`. Basically I would like to do `row(1)*R`, check value, update, `row(2)*R`, etc

This is my current code:

```
P6 = rand(24);
R = rand(24,1);
best=100;
for i=1:24
    X(i)=P6(i,:)*R
    if X(i) <= best
        best = X(i)
    end
end
```

Presents errors such as:

> Attempting to access X(3); index out of bounds because number(X)=1

and

> matrix dimensions must agree

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I will do so in future posts! I did mean dot product, I would like to obtain a value that I can check to see if it is the lowest value calculated. If the calculated value is lower than the "best" stored prior then I would like to update the best to show the global best.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is not correct.
If you multiply `p6` to `R` you can get minimum by `min` function:

```
best = 100;
result = P6*R;
[best_val, best_ind] = min(result);
% check best_val with best value at the end
```

Comment: @Guto yes. It might be none of value of `result` is not less than the initial value `100`.

Comment: Thanks for your response! The purpose of my code was to show what row iteration would yield the best response (sorry I didn't include that before). Do you know of a way to show where the minimum value is located? Thanks!